I want to change kibana logo in version 8.15 with some other logo and change the text too
I want to change elasticsearch logo from my kibana Iframe or atleast hide that logo from I frame and instead of loading elastic, I want to show some custom message
I have make changes in template.js in version 7.x and got successfull results but in 8.15 making changes for logo is not applicable in my IFrame and even I can't be able to hide that logo.

If you are using Elastic Cloud or if you have an elastic license, you can change the you can change the followings in Kibana => Advanced Settings => Global Settings

Custom logo
Organization name
Page title
Favicon


